# How to install WordPress on sub directory in ubuntu 16.4 in same vhost with AngularJS

Tags: directory, nginx

I have vhost for the main domain **www.example.com**. and I want to install WordPress in a subdirectory called **news** (**www.example.com/news/**).

This is the vhost configuration file.

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle_example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com_private_key.key;


  location / {
    root /www/sites/Yoga-Frontend/dist/Yoga-Frontend;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /news {
    root /www/sites/Yoga-Frontend/dist/Yoga-Frontend/news;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /news/index.php?$args /news/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.error.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
  }
}
```

Problem: once I enter **www.example.com/news/**, it always redirect to **www.example.com.**

Comment: This is not really WordPress specific (as WP doesn't even get loaded). You might have better luck on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Besides that: Your `location /news` block seems off to me. Why is `/news` used for `try_files` as well? And does the sub-location block really work like that?

Comment: Because of the root block is for Angular only serve HTML and /news block need to run PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  root /www/sites/Yoga-Frontend/dist/Yoga-Frontend;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/bundle_example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com_private_key.key;


  location /yoga {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /yoga/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/yoga)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you install Wordpress in the /yoga subfolder in /www/sites/Yoga-Frontend/dist/Yoga-Frontend with this config?